In finding all the possible values of the cos (z)= 3i i am left with an odd expression that i would like to simplify.
Calculate all values of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\cos z=3i$
$\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=3i\ \Leftrightarrow e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=6i$
$\Leftrightarrow e^{iz}+e^{-iz}-6i=0{\ } $
let $\mathrm{\ }u=e^{iz}$
$\Leftrightarrow u+u^{-1}-6i=0$      multiply by u
$\Leftrightarrow u^2-6iu+1=0$      quadratic equation
$u=\frac{-(-6i)\pm\sqrt{(-6i)^2-4(1)(1)}}{2(1)}=\frac{6i\pm\sqrt{36i^2-4}}{2}=\frac{6i\pm i\sqrt{2^2\cdot10}}{2}=3i\pm i\sqrt{10}$
Therefore:
$e^{iz}=3i\pm i\sqrt{10}\Leftrightarrow iz=\ln(3i\pm i\sqrt{10})$
The problem is how do I treat bracketed expressions. Is there a way to simplify this expression. Currently I get:
$\Leftrightarrow{\ }z=\dfrac{i\cdot\ln(3i\pm i\sqrt{10})}{i^2}
\Leftrightarrow{\ }z=-i\ln(3i\pm i\sqrt{10})$

Factor out $i$ and use $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$?

Going back to naive basics.  If $z=a+bi$ then $e^z = e^a e^{bi}$ where $e^a\in \mathbb R^+$ and $|e^{bi}|$.  Meanwhile $e^{bi} = c + si$ where $c=\cos b\in \mathbb R$ and $s=\sin b\in \mathbb R$ and $e^{-bi} = c-si$.
So don't we have $e^{z} + e^{-z} = e^ac(c+si) + e^{-a}c(c-si) =6i$ so $(e^a + \frac 1{e^a})c = 0$ and $(e^a -e^{-a})s = 6$.  So $c=\cos b = 0$ so $b=k\pi +\frac \pi 2$ for any $k \in \mathbb Z$.
And so $s=\sin b = \pm 1$ and $e^a -e^{-a} = \pm 6$.  Replace $u = e^a$ we get $u-\frac 1u = \begin{cases}6& u> 1\-6& u< 1\end{cases}$.  Anything wrong with that?

$$z=-i\ln(3i±i\sqrt{10})$$
$$=-i\ln(i(3±\sqrt{10}))$$
$$=-i\ln(i)-i\ln(3±\sqrt{10})$$
$$=\ln(i^{-i})-i\ln(3±\sqrt{10})$$
By Euler's identity,
$e^{πi}=-1\implies e^{πi}=i^2\implies e^{\frac{π}{2}}=i^\frac{1}{i}=i^{-i}$
Thus answer is
$$\frac{π}{2}-i\ln(3±\sqrt{10})$$

The equation $\cos(z)=3i$ does not have a unique solution.

If you are trying to find all solutions, well there is not just one or two, there could be infinite. The quadratic equation you have obtained is assuming principal solution.
Consider a different approach, where we let $z = x + iy$ and both $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$
Then,
$\cos{z} = \cos{(x + iy)} = \cos x\cdot\cos{iy} - \sin x\cdot\sin{iy} = 3i$
By complex-trig identities we know,
$\cos(iy) = \dfrac{e^{-y}+e^{y}}{2} = \cosh(y)$ and $\sin(iy) = \dfrac{e^{-y} - e^{y}}{2} = i\sinh(y)$
and so,
$\cos x\cdot\cos{iy} - \sin x\cdot\sin{iy} = 3i = \cos x\cdot\cosh{y} - i\sin x\cdot\sinh{y}$
Since, $3i$ is purely imaginary, $ \cos x\cdot\cosh{y} = 0$. Note that, $\cosh{y} \ge 1, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, only $\cos{x} = 0$. Thus, $x = \dfrac{(2n+1)\cdot\pi}{2}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. See that there could possibly be infinite solutions.

Going back to naive basics.  If $z=a+bi$ then $e^z = e^a e^{bi}$ where $e^a\in \mathbb R^+$ and $e^{bi}\in \mathbb C;|e^{bi}|=1$.  Meanwhile $e^{bi} = c + si$ where $c=\cos b\in \mathbb R$ and $s=\sin b\in \mathbb R$ and $e^{-bi} =c-si$ (where $\cos(-b)=c; \sin(-b)=-s$.
So don't we have $e^{z} + e^{-z} = e^ac(c+si) + e^{-a}c(c-si) =6i$? so $(e^a + \frac 1{e^a})c = 0$ and $(e^a -e^{-a})s = 6$.  So $c=\cos b = 0$ so $b=2k\pi \pm\frac \pi 2$ for any $k \in \mathbb Z$.
And so $s=\sin b = \pm 1$ and $e^a -e^{-a} = \pm 6$.  Replace $u = e^a$ we get $u-\frac 1u = \begin{cases}6& u> 1\\-6& u< 1\end{cases}$
$u^2 \pm 6u -1=0$ gives us $u=\frac {\pm 6\pm \sqrt{40}}2=\pm 3 \pm \sqrt{10}$.  But $a=\ln u$ so $u>0$.  So if $u > 1$  then $a=\ln(\sqrt{10}+3)$ and if $u < 1$ then $a=-\ln(\sqrt{10}+3)$.  [Side note $\sqrt{10} -3 =\frac 1{\sqrt{10}+3}$...]
And so the solutions to $z$ are $\{ \ln(3+\sqrt{10})+(2k\pi + \frac \pi 2)i,  -\ln(\sqrt{10}+3) + (2n\pi -\frac \pi 2)i \}$. (infinitely many of course)
The key is that when a $\cos$ is strictly imaginary the real part must be the inverse $\cos$ of $0$ (i.e. $2k\pi \pm \frac {\pi}2$) and similary if strictly real.  (I think)
.....
At least.... I think so.  Seems a little naive to me and it's actually been years since I've done something like this and I feel I've probably done something wrong and/or forgetting well-known advanced techniques.
I'm posting this until someone tells me if I'm making an idiotic mistake.
